Junction diode "built-in" voltages
When a PN Junction terminal are left open-circuited, the voltage measured between then is zero. The Junction voltage Vo does not appears. Because similar built in voltages arise at metal semiconductor terminal. But how this built in voltages arise????

Lots of explanations online of how this works, try Google.
